# Entity Framework link related entities by lookup in a dropdown box

Tags: entity-framework

I find myself repeating the following pattern when a user is required to link two entities together and it feels wrong.

I have two entities, Site and User say, a user msut have a site and a site can have many users. On the add user form the available Sites are displayed as a DropDown List.

Example Code:

```
public class Site()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  

    public int SiteId { get; set; }       
    public Site Site { get; set; }  
}

public class UserViewModel()
{
     public User User { get; set; }
     public List<Site> AvailableSites { get; set; }
}
```

Add User View

```
@model SomeNameSpace.UserViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <div>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.User.Site)</div>
        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.User.Site.Id,
              new SelectList(Model.AvailiableSites,"Id","Name"))
        </div>
    </div>

   <--- the rest of the view --- >
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    UserViewModel u = new UserViewModel();
    u.AvailableSites = context.Sites.ToList();

    return View(u);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(UserViewModel model)
{  
    //THIS FEELS WRONG
    Site s = context.Sites.Where(s=>s.Id == model.User.Site,Id).FirstOrDefault();
    model.User.Site = s;
    context.Users.Add(model.User);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It seems odd to be looking up the site in the controller, I expected the dropdown to link the two entities together - it displays the site name correctly - but it only sets the UserViewModel.User.Site.Id value.

Am I missing something, or is this the preferred/correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to grab the whole entity in order to link it. As long as the FK has been properly set up, all you would need to do is make sure that the FK's ID property has been set (which it looks like you have, considering that you're using `model.User.SiteId` to grab the entity).

EF doesn't need to know the full entity in order to link them. It just needs to know its ID. Also, sometimes it can be bad to assign the full entity. Depending on how you do it you could create duplicates.